# Creating an Angular button component that can be either an anchor or a button element

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-directive

I'm working on an Angular project and I need to create a button component that can function as either an anchor (`<a>`) or a button (`<button>`) based on the use case. I want the flexibility to dynamically generate the HTML for the button component based on its properties.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
// Initial attempt
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Color, Corner, Size, Variant } from 'src/app/type/core';
import { NgIconComponent } from '@ng-icons/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mr-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgIconComponent],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() color: Color = 'primary';
  @Input() size: Size = 'md';
  @Input() corner: Corner = 'md';
  @Input() variant: Variant = 'solid';
  @Input() fluid: boolean = false;
  @Input() icon!: string;
  @Input() isLoading: boolean = false;
}

// this is the component HTML file

<button
  [ngClass]="{ btn__fluid: fluid }"
  class="btn btn__{{ variant }} u_{{ color }} corner__{{ corner }} u_singleline"
>
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading; else buttonContent">
  <span>Loading...</span>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #buttonContent>
  <ng-icon *ngIf="!!icon" strokeWidth="1.5" [name]="icon"></ng-icon>
  <span class="btn--text"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
</ng-template>

</button>
// And this how I call the component 
<mr-button variant='solid'>Hello world</mr-button>
```

```js
// Second attempt
import { Input, Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { Color, Corner, Size, Variant } from 'src/app/type/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mr-button]',
})
export class ButtonComponent {
   @Input() @HostBinding('class') hostClasses: string = 'btn u_singleline';

  @Input() icon!: string;

  @Input() set size(value: Size) {
    value = value ?? 'md';
    this.hostClasses = this.updateHostClasses(
      this.hostClasses,
      `size-${value}`
    );
  }

  @Input() set color(value: Color) {
    value = value ?? 'primary';
    this.hostClasses = this.updateHostClasses(this.hostClasses, `btn_${value}`);
  }

  @HostBinding('btn__fluid') @Input() fluid = false;

  @Input() set corner(value: Corner) {
    value = value ?? 'md';
    this.hostClasses = this.updateHostClasses(
      this.hostClasses,
      `corner-${value}`
    );
  }

  @Input() set variant(value: Corner) {
    value = value ?? 'solid';
    this.hostClasses = this.updateHostClasses(
      this.hostClasses,
      `btn__${value}`
    );
  }

  private updateHostClasses(existingClasses: string, newClass: string): string {
    return `${existingClasses} ${newClass}`.trim();
  } // ...
}
```

With this It fixes my problem but the new problem I has is now When I want to call the component I need to do it from scratch

```
// And this how I call the component 
<button mr-button variant='solid'>
  <ng-icon *ngIf="!!icon" strokeWidth="1.5" [name]="icon"></ng-icon>
  <span class="btn--text"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
</mr-button>

// And this with the loading

<button mr-button variant='solid'>
   <mr-spinner></mr-spinner>
  <span class="btn--text">Loading...</span>
</mr-button>
```

How can I achieve the same benefits with the second attempt that I received from the initial attempt, please?

Any guidance or examples on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expect button component to accept anchor or a button element

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same selector idea but on a component ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a[mr-button], button[my-button]',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgIconComponent],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
})
```

That works too !

Comment: Thanks for the reply But I try It but I have two problems with it 
1- how can I told the html to use either a or button is this <button
  [ngClass]="{ btn__fluid: fluid }"
  class="btn btn__{{ variant }} u_{{ color }} corner__{{ corner }} u_singleline"
>

2- How can I make it accept all the HTMLElement properties for this element and generate an error if it encounters an unsupported property, such as 'href' in 'a' or 'type='submit'' in 'button'?

Thanks a lot, @Matthieu Riegler!

Comment: Use host classes if you need to customize the host element. This way you won't have the `button` in your template.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example, please? I am currently working on an Angular project, but I come from a React background OR a blog post that I can get more info from please $